# XSD validation failure

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

I am working on validating the XML against the XSD using below java function. However, I am getting below exception at below line. Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath)). Please find attached XSD and XML.

Exception: s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'definitions' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'. Screenshots, XSD and XML is attached.

Code snippet:

```
public static boolean validateXMLSchema(String xsdPath, String xmlPath){
  try {
    SchemaFactory factory =
            SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));
  } catch (IOException | SAXException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/AB_IExposureAPI_v1" name="AB_IExposureAPI_v1" xmlns:gwsoap="http://guidewire.com/ws/soapheaders" xmlns:gwwsdl="http://guidewire.com/pl/wsdl" xmlns:pogo="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequest" xmlns:pogo2="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureResponse" xmlns:pogo3="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/Error" xmlns:pogo4="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/domain/Exposure" xmlns:pogo5="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToReopen" xmlns:pogo6="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToClose" xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/AB_IExposureAPI_v1" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/AB_IExposureAPI_v1" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:import namespace="http://guidewire.com/ws/soapheaders" schemaLocation="../../../../../../../gw/xsd/guidewire/soapheaders.xsd"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToClose"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToReopen"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/domain/Exposure"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/Error"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureResponse"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequest"/>
      <!-- getExposures(ExposureRequest) : ExposureResponse -->
      <xs:element name="getExposures">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="request" type="pogo:ExposureRequest" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="getExposuresResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return" type="pogo2:ExposureResponse" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="WsiAuthenticationException">
        <xs:complexType/>
      </xs:element>
      <!-- reopenExposure(ExposureRequestToReopen) : ExposureResponse -->
      <xs:element name="reopenExposure">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="request" type="pogo5:ExposureRequestToReopen" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="reopenExposureResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return" type="pogo2:ExposureResponse" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <!-- closeExposure(ExposureRequestToClose) : ExposureResponse -->
      <xs:element name="closeExposure">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="request" type="pogo6:ExposureRequestToClose" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="closeExposureResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return" type="pogo2:ExposureResponse" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequest" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToClose"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToReopen"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/domain/Exposure"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/Error"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureResponse"/>
      <xs:complexType name="ExposureRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="ClaimNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="ExposureId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="ExposureNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureResponse" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToClose"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToReopen"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/domain/Exposure"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/Error"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequest"/>
      <xs:complexType name="ExposureResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Errors" minOccurs="0" gw:viewas="array" xmlns:gw="http://guidewire.com/xsd">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Entry" type="pogo3:Error" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="Exposures" minOccurs="0" gw:viewas="array" xmlns:gw="http://guidewire.com/xsd">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Entry" type="pogo4:Exposure" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="ResponseStatus" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/Error" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToClose"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToReopen"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/domain/Exposure"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureResponse"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequest"/>
      <xs:complexType name="Error">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/domain/Exposure" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:gw="http://guidewire.com/xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToClose"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToReopen"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/Error"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureResponse"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequest"/>
      <xs:complexType name="Exposure">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="AssignedUserId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="ClaimNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="CoverageCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="IncidentID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="Number" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="ReopenDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" gw:type="java.util.Date"/>
          <xs:element name="SegmentCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="StatusCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToReopen" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToClose"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/domain/Exposure"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/Error"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureResponse"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequest"/>
      <xs:complexType name="ExposureRequestToReopen">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="Exposure" type="pogo:ExposureRequest" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="ReasonCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToClose" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequestToReopen"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/domain/Exposure"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/Error"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureResponse"/>
      <xs:import namespace="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequest"/>
      <xs:complexType name="ExposureRequestToClose">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="Exposure" type="pogo:ExposureRequest" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="OutcomeCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:portType name="AB_IExposureAPI_v1PortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="getExposures">
      <wsdl:input name="getExposures" message="tns:getExposures"/>
      <wsdl:output name="getExposuresResponse" message="tns:getExposuresResponse"/>
      <wsdl:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException" message="tns:WsiAuthenticationException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="reopenExposure">
      <wsdl:input name="reopenExposure" message="tns:reopenExposure"/>
      <wsdl:output name="reopenExposureResponse" message="tns:reopenExposureResponse"/>
      <wsdl:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException" message="tns:WsiAuthenticationException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="closeExposure">
      <wsdl:input name="closeExposure" message="tns:closeExposure"/>
      <wsdl:output name="closeExposureResponse" message="tns:closeExposureResponse"/>
      <wsdl:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException" message="tns:WsiAuthenticationException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="AB_IExposureAPI_v1Soap12Binding" type="tns:AB_IExposureAPI_v1PortType">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getExposures">
      <soap12:operation soapActionRequired="false" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="getExposures">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:gw-authentication" part="gw-authentication" use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:gw-language-only" part="gw-language-only" use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:gw-locale-only" part="gw-locale-only" use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:gw-traceability-id" part="gw-traceability-id" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getExposuresResponse">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException">
        <soap12:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="reopenExposure">
      <soap12:operation soapActionRequired="false" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="reopenExposure">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:gw-authentication" part="gw-authentication" use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:gw-language-only" part="gw-language-only" use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:gw-locale-only" part="gw-locale-only" use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:gw-traceability-id" part="gw-traceability-id" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="reopenExposureResponse">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException">
        <soap12:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="closeExposure">
      <soap12:operation soapActionRequired="false" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="closeExposure">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:gw-authentication" part="gw-authentication" use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:gw-language-only" part="gw-language-only" use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:gw-locale-only" part="gw-locale-only" use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:gw-traceability-id" part="gw-traceability-id" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="closeExposureResponse">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException">
        <soap12:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="AB_IExposureAPI_v1Soap11Binding" type="tns:AB_IExposureAPI_v1PortType">
    <soap11:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getExposures">
      <soap11:operation style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="getExposures">
        <soap11:body use="literal"/>
        <soap11:header message="tns:gw-authentication" part="gw-authentication" use="literal"/>
        <soap11:header message="tns:gw-language-only" part="gw-language-only" use="literal"/>
        <soap11:header message="tns:gw-locale-only" part="gw-locale-only" use="literal"/>
        <soap11:header message="tns:gw-traceability-id" part="gw-traceability-id" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getExposuresResponse">
        <soap11:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException">
        <soap11:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="reopenExposure">
      <soap11:operation style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="reopenExposure">
        <soap11:body use="literal"/>
        <soap11:header message="tns:gw-authentication" part="gw-authentication" use="literal"/>
        <soap11:header message="tns:gw-language-only" part="gw-language-only" use="literal"/>
        <soap11:header message="tns:gw-locale-only" part="gw-locale-only" use="literal"/>
        <soap11:header message="tns:gw-traceability-id" part="gw-traceability-id" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="reopenExposureResponse">
        <soap11:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException">
        <soap11:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="closeExposure">
      <soap11:operation style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="closeExposure">
        <soap11:body use="literal"/>
        <soap11:header message="tns:gw-authentication" part="gw-authentication" use="literal"/>
        <soap11:header message="tns:gw-language-only" part="gw-language-only" use="literal"/>
        <soap11:header message="tns:gw-locale-only" part="gw-locale-only" use="literal"/>
        <soap11:header message="tns:gw-traceability-id" part="gw-traceability-id" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="closeExposureResponse">
        <soap11:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException">
        <soap11:fault name="WsiAuthenticationException" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="AB_IExposureAPI_v1">
    <wsdl:port name="AB_IExposureAPI_v1Soap12Port" binding="tns:AB_IExposureAPI_v1Soap12Binding">
      <soap12:address location="https://navigator.dev-a.abcec.com/cc/ws/com/abc/pm/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/AB_IExposureAPI_v1"/>
      <gwwsdl:address location="${cc}/ws/com/abc/pm/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/AB_IExposureAPI_v1"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="AB_IExposureAPI_v1Soap11Port" binding="tns:AB_IExposureAPI_v1Soap11Binding">
      <soap11:address location="https://navigator.dev-a.abcec.com/cc/ws/com/abc/pm/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/AB_IExposureAPI_v1/soap11"/>
      <gwwsdl:address location="${cc}/ws/com/abc/pm/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/AB_IExposureAPI_v1/soap11"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
  <wsdl:message name="getExposures">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getExposures"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getExposuresResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getExposuresResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="WsiAuthenticationException">
    <wsdl:part name="WsiAuthenticationException" element="tns:WsiAuthenticationException"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="reopenExposure">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:reopenExposure"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="reopenExposureResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:reopenExposureResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="closeExposure">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:closeExposure"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="closeExposureResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:closeExposureResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="gw-authentication">
    <wsdl:part name="gw-authentication" element="gwsoap:authentication"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="gw-locale-only">
    <wsdl:part name="gw-locale-only" element="gwsoap:gw_locale"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="gw-language-only">
    <wsdl:part name="gw-language-only" element="gwsoap:gw_language"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="gw-transaction-id">
    <wsdl:part name="gw-transaction-id" element="gwsoap:transaction_id"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="gw-traceability-id">
    <wsdl:part name="gw-traceability-id" element="gwsoap:traceability_id"/>
  </wsdl:message>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soap1="http://guidewire.com/ws/soapheaders" xmlns:AB="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/AB_IExposureAPI_v1" xmlns:exp="http://google.com/cl/cc/webservices/exposure/model/v1/service/ExposureRequest"><soap:Header><soap1:authentication><soap1:username>su</soap1:username><soap1:password>gw</soap1:password></soap1:authentication></soap:Header><soap:Body><AB:getExposures><AB:request><exp:ClaimNumber>123</exp:ClaimNumber><exp:ExposureId>1</exp:ExposureId><exp:ExposureNumber>01</exp:ExposureNumber></AB:request></AB:getExposures></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSD that tried to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1. All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Please find attached XML and XSD. The version is 1.0.

Comment: stackoverflow.com doesn't support attachments. Just edit your original question, and add ##1-2 as text.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Edited the original questions and attached XSD and XML.

Answer (score 0):

The shown code sample is not a W3C XSD schema, rather it incorporates parts of such a schema or seems to contain various schemas. Perhaps a WSDL tool knows how to process such an input format but an XSD based validator certainly won't do that.

Comment: Is there any way to write the code for WSDL tool which considers this XSD as a valid type? If not then what are the options?

Comment: @AK2412, I am sorry, I don't know enough about WSDL to tell which tool or whether a certain tool does know how to validate your input. As I said, it is not an XSD schema, rather it has some other elements that then contain XSD schemas.